# keyframe animation transform not running in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

The below appears to work on Firefox and Safari, and even IE! But *not* in Chrome.

*(Works in Firefox and IE, but if you open it in Chrome you see absolutely nothing!)*

```
@keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {
    transform:  translate(-402px,55px)  ;
  }
  4% {
    transform:  translate(-333px,26px)  ;
  }
  9% {
    transform:  translate(-257px,-13px)  ;
  }
  14% {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because @keyframes rule is [not supported](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) by Chrome yet. You have to use prefixed rule @-webkit-keyframes as in example:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    0% { }
    100% { }
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes animation {
    0% { }
    100% { }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[I'm sure](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) – [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uLoa1Lya/)

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me! Are you sure it works on transform?

Comment: `@keyframes` is supported *by now* of course https://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes (for any future googlers)